# How can I get WordPress to pull all description metadata fields without knowing their names or length?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I get WordPress to find and display all of the descriptions in use for a user? Typically, a user on our site will have a description in 2-3 languages. The additional description fields in other languages are created by a plugin (and manually filled in by our editors). Currently, ANOTHER plugin uses this code to display the main description for a user:

```
$biography = get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user->user_id )
```

However, I need it to pull ALL description fields such as:

```
$biography = get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user->user_id ) . $biography = get_the_author_meta( 'description_zh', $user->user_id )
```

But this is clunky, and I won't know ahead of time how many languages will be added to the site. I thought maybe something like this might work, but no luck:

```
$biography = get_the_author_meta( 'description.*', $user->user_id )
```

I'm new to PHP, so any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$bio_meta = (array)get_user_meta( $user->user_id );

foreach ( $bio_meta as $key => $value_array ) {
    if ( strpos( $key, 'description' ) !== false ) {
        $description_values[] = $value_array[0];
    }
}
$biography = implode( ' ', $description_values );
```

Turning the meta results into an array makes life easier, then just check each key that begins with "description."

If you wanted the output to include the key, you could change

```
$description_values[] = $value_array[0];
```

into this:

```
$description_values[] = array( $key => $value_array[0] );
```

Comment: This is spitting out an error message because it expects a string and is getting an array. How can I pass the values as a string back into the $biography variable (which is used by a plugin)?

Comment: Worked on my end.  I assume the error says strpos expects value 2 to be a string?  If so, print or var_dump the $bio_meta variable and see how the array is structured.

Comment: The error is: "trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array," and the error seems to be keeping me from printing anything (or I don't understand where printed result would actually appear on the site).

Comment: Sounds like you're passing it to the other plugin and it doesn't like it.  Does your original $biography variable work (the second one with two keys)?  If so, what does print_r($biography); look like?

Comment: It prints out every description in the default language (English) but none of them from, say, description_zh. Thanks for sticking with me on this!

Comment: $biography = get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user->user_id ) . $biography = get_the_author_meta( 'description_zh', $user->user_id );
print_r($biography);
That works and only outputs English?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209402/discussion-between-fxrgc-and-westcoast-509).